# Finding closure of a set

Tags: general-topology

Let us consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology on it and let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. What will be the closure of $\lbrace x+r: r\in \mathbb{Q} \rbrace$?

Comment: What is the closure if $x = 0$?

Comment: @ Fischer: $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Right. And how do closure and translation relate?

Answer (score 1):

This is the closure of a translate of the rational numbers. Since the rational numbers are dense in the reals, this closure is simply the reals.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see directly that the closure is ${\mathbb R}$, note that for any $y \in {\mathbb R}$ you can find a sequence of rationals $\{q_n\}$ that converges to $y - x$ since the rationals are dense.  Then $\{q_n + x\}$ is a sequence in your set that converges to $(y-x)+x = y$.  Since $y \in {\mathbb R}$ was aribitrary, the closure is ${\mathbb R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see this: The map $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $t\mapsto x+t$ is a homeomorphism, so maps dense sets to dense sets, and in particular maps $\Bbb Q$ to the set in question.

Answer (score 0):

$(\Bbb R,+,0,-)$ is a topological group, that is a group such that the addition $$+:\Bbb R\times \Bbb R\to \Bbb R,\ (x,y)\mapsto x+y$$ and the negation $$-:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,\ x\mapsto-x$$ are continuous. If we fix $r\in\Bbb R$, then $\lambda_r:x\mapsto r+x$ is continuous. So $\Bbb R=\lambda_r(\Bbb R)=\lambda_r(\overline{\Bbb Q})\subseteq\overline{\lambda_r(\Bbb Q)}=\overline{\Bbb Q+r}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** We want to show that any real number $y$ can be approximated arbitrarily closely by numbers of the form $x+r$. So we want to show that by a proper choice of $r$, the "difference" $|y-(x+r)|$ can be made arbitrarily small. Note that
$$|y-(x+r)|=|(y-x)-r|.$$